# Cat attacks me then beats up his brother

Tags: cats, aggression, dominance

I was cutting fabric on my worktable and Milo (age 9, neutered male) was sitting on the fabric. I nudged his hind left foot, the only part of him that was in my way. He reared up and slapped my head with his claws out, right-left-right-left. Both he and I were shocked. I said "Milo!" and he jumped down and ran out of the room. The rest of the day he repeatedly attacked his littermate Max (NM), biting his hind leg. Max ended up under the bed shivering. How could I have eased the situation? I've had the pair for almost a year and this has never happened before. Both are strictly indoors.

Comment: Was he napping when you nudged him?

Comment: This question sounds like a news headline: "Cat attacks owner, beats his brother up and robs a pet store at gunpoint."

Comment: I can't speak to attacking his brother, because I only have one cat. However, when I am doing crafts, the cat often sits on my craft and becomes extremely territorial. Even ignoring her and trying to continue as best I can can lead to an attack on me. Picking her up is out of the question. I resorted to the spray bottle. You can shake the bottle, spray past or over your cat, and then finally spray him. Next time he should have learned that the water shaking sound means get down and hopefully you won't need to actually spray him.

Answer (score -1):

He may be trying to defend himself from you nudging his hand, and left foot. Sometime cats defend themselves when they feel like you were bothering them, it's completely normal for them to act like this, Milo might had evolved with that feature. Also if he's attacking his Littermate, he mighted had learned that from his ancestors. In this case take Max and Milo to the vet.

Comment: This is a behavioral issue, not a medical one.